# Technical difference between methods of AsyncTask Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to know the technical difference between all the four methods of AsyncTask.

- onPreExecute()
- doInbackgroud()
- onPublishProgress()
- onPostExecute()

I dont want to ask about the order of invoking methods. I want to know the main technical difference between these methods which differentiate them from each other.

Comment: You'd need to define what you mean by "technical difference". From a language perspective, there's no technical difference as they are all _instance_ methods (non-static). Sure, they differ in terms of (lack of) return type and parameters, but that's really something you can figure out from their very signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Developer Page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

> `onPreExecute()`, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
>   This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing
>   a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> `doInBackground(Params...)`, invoked on the background thread
>   immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>   to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>   parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>   result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>   passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>   publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>   These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`, invoked on the UI thread after a call
>   to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.
>
> `onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter.